# Sony A7S / Smart Remote Control app shutter speed

Tags: camera, sony

There appears to be a shutter speed bug with the Sony A7S and the Smart Remote Control app (version 4.10).

"0.6" seconds is listed by `-getSupportedShutterSpeed`, but when that speed is POST'ed with `-setShutterSpeed`, an HTTP error code of 500 is returned (without the speed being set).

Other shutter speeds appear to work.

Comment: Can you post your request and response JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you statement. Sony person must fix *mulfunction*.

I experience same phenomena in A7R2. I'm really annoyed by this "bug". My current environment is firmware v3.0, Remote Control App v4.10. This phenomena has kept from firmware v2.0 and Remote contorol App V4.0, as far as I tried.

I make one-line command in Linux to prove mulfunction. Results are below.

> $ one_liners/setShutterSpeed.py 0.8 {"method": "setShutterSpeed",
>   "params": ["0.8"], "id": 1, "version": "1.0"} {"result":[0],"id":1}
>
> $ one_liners/setShutterSpeed.py 0.6 {"method": "setShutterSpeed",
>   "params": ["0.6"], "id": 1, "version": "1.0"} API camera failed.
>   {"method": "setShutterSpeed", "params": ["0.6"], "id": 1, "version":
>   "1.0"}
>
> $ one_liners/setShutterSpeed.py 0.5 {"method": "setShutterSpeed",
>   "params": ["0.5"], "id": 1, "version": "1.0"} {"result":[0],"id":1}

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out what is happening.

For a shutter speed of 0.6 seconds, one **must** send the quoted string "0.6\"".

For other speeds like 0.5 seconds and 0.8 seconds, strings of either the form "0.8" or the quoted form with seconds unit, "0.8\"" both works.